# How to gamma correct all visual elements in Swift

Tags: swift, colors, metal, gamma

I want to present visual stimuli in the screen with lineal values for the luminance. A value of 0.5 must have half the luminance than a value of 1.0.

First I have measured the value gamma of the screen using a colorimeter.

Then I compute the stimuli in a metal view. I compute the value of color(r, g, b, alpha) for each point.
In the last line of the kernel I use the value of gamma measured  to “correct” the value of luminance when writing the texture:

```
output.write(pow(color, 1 / gamma), gid);
```

If I want to draw some simple things, as labels or texts, outside the metal view, I can modify the color using the same idea:

```
color = pow(color, 1 / gamma)
```

Both cases work fine, but I can’t blend the text over the metal view if the value of alpha is different of one because I am not in lineal space anymore.

Is threre a way to make a transformation of color of all the elements on the screen after all the blending of views have been done?

Comment: In theory, if you translate your color to a calibrated color space (regardless of which one), the colors are within the color space's and display's gamuts, and your display is properly calibrated, it should work automatically, right? Metal always works with linear RGB within shaders, so take that into account. Also, is this macOS or iOS? For macOS, you can set the color space of windows.

Comment: It is for iOS. But the problem is that what I want to display is directly the lineal RGB, because this app is for scientific visual experiments. The metal view works with lineal RGB but when the calculations are done the image is transformed applying a gamma to match our eyes non linear response to luminance. This last transformation is what I want to avoid, my solution was powering to 1/gamma to compensate this final transformation. I suppose I would have to do everything including rendering the texts inside the mtkview.